# I can not bind to the fragment in "View". getView() does not work :(

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-activity

Can not create objects think that an error is contained in Tab1.java

In Tab1 contains the timer. Accordingly, I sent you to see "layout".

**Tab.java**

```
package com.android.example;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private TextView tvDay, tvHour, tvMinute, tvSecond, tvEvent;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout1, linearLayout2;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        initUI();
        countDownStart();
        return v;
    }


    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void initUI() {
        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.ll2);
        tvDay = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTimerDay);
        tvHour = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTimerHour);
        tvMinute = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTimerMinute);
        tvSecond = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtTimerSecond);
        tvEvent = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvevent);
    }

    // //////////////COUNT DOWN START/////////////////////////
    public void countDownStart() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "yyyy-MM-dd");
                    // Here Set your Event Date
                    Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse("2016-12-30");
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    if (!currentDate.after(futureDate)) {
                        long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                                - currentDate.getTime();
                        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                        diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                        long seconds = diff / 1000;
                        tvDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                        tvHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                        tvMinute.setText("" + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                        tvSecond.setText("" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    } else {
                        linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tvEvent.setText("Android Event Start");
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        // handler.removeMessages(0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }

    // //////////////COUNT DOWN END/////////////////////////
}
```

**MainActivity.java**
Then connect the fragments

```
package com.android.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaring Your View and Variables

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;

    int Numboftabs =3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CharSequence Titles[]= {getResources().getString(R.string.titles), getResources().getString(R.string.result), getResources().getString(R.string.contacts)};


        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**tab_1.xml**
it is layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvevent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Android Event Start"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerDay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerDay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Days"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerHour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerHour"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Hour"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerMinute"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerMinute"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Minute"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_back"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimerSecond"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_TimerSecond"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Second"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Gradle error:**
I can not figure out the error. Please do not "write" because I am a beginner programmer :)

```
03-19 18:00:55.154 28193-28193/? E/Zygote: v2
03-19 18:00:55.154 28193-28193/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10140
03-19 18:00:55.154 28193-28193/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-19 18:00:55.154 28193-28193/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-A300F_5.0.2-1_0026
03-19 18:00:55.154 28193-28193/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
03-19 18:00:55.154 28193-28193/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-19 18:00:55.174 28193-28193/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
03-19 18:00:55.184 28193-28193/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
03-19 18:00:55.184 28193-28193/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
03-19 18:00:55.374 28193-28193/com.android.example D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
03-19 18:00:55.714 28193-28240/com.android.example D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
03-19 18:00:55.784 28193-28193/com.android.example W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for Tab2{3edefe8b #0 id=0x7f0c0052} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
03-19 18:00:55.834 28193-28193/com.android.example D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-19 18:00:55.844 28193-28193/com.android.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.android.example, PID: 28193
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.android.example.Tab1.initUI(Tab1.java:36)
                                                                                     at com.android.example.Tab1.onCreateView(Tab1.java:28)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5653)
                                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2748)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17826)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1174)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1395)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5873)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.j
03-19 18:00:57.404 28193-28193/com.android.example I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28193 SIG: 9
```

Comment: ViewGroup v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false); initUI(v) and in initUI(ViewGroup v), do something like v.getViewById(R.id.name);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getView() returns the view which was returned by OnCreateView();

It will be null till onCreateView() returns.

You need to make sure you call getView() only after onCreateView() returns. To do this, you can move initUi() and countdownStart() inside onViewCreated(), which is called after onCreateView() returns.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        return v;
     }

public void onViewCreated(View container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        initUI();
        countDownStart();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can pass the layout inflated to the function initUI(), as others have mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the result of inflater.inflate() to initUI(). Not sure, but I think getView() returns null because the system have not received your newly created view yet (you just created it, but it will be bound to the fragment only after return from onCreateView).